Discrepancy in open high low close value for straddle chart in pine script
Below is the code i am using for genearte candle stick chart for straddle options for nifty. But when i plot same chart on tradingview the high low values are different than they should be. Can someone please help me resolve the issue to get correct values? I tried using barmerge.gaps and lookahead but it did not make any difference. Any help is appreciated.
//@version=5
indicator('Straddle', shorttitle='Options_Straddle', timeframe='', overlay = false)
OptionsChart1 = input.symbol('', title='OptionsChart1 Symbol')
OptionsChart2 = input.symbol('', title='OptionsChart2 Symbol')
_developingLineStyle = 'Combined'

var o = 0.00
var h = 0.00
var l = 0.00
var c = 0.00

[oo, hh, ll, cc] = request.security(OptionsChart1, timeframe.period, [open, high, low, close], barmerge.gaps_on)
[ooo , hhh, lll , ccc]= request.security(OptionsChart2, timeframe.period, [open, high, low, close], barmerge.gaps_on)

if _developingLineStyle == 'Combined'

    o := oo + ooo
    h := hh + hhh
    l := ll + lll
    c := cc + ccc

// if _developingLineStyle == 'Difference'

//     o := oo - ooo
//     h := hh - hhh
//     l := ll - lll
//     c := cc - ccc

// if _developingLineStyle == 'Ratio'
//     o := oo / ooo
//     h := hh / hhh
//     l := ll / lll
//     c := cc / ccc


ourWickColor = c > c[1] ? color.green : color.red
plotcandle(o, h , l, c, title='OptionsStraddle', color=ourWickColor, force_overlay = false)**strong text**


What are the two symbols you are trying to get data from? What timeframe you are trying to get data from? What is your chart's timeframe?

Sir, you can pick any options symbol for eg Nifty 23500 put and Nifty 23500 call both expiring on 21st november 2024. Time frame i am checking data on 5min. Chart time frame is also 5 min

This is indicator i am trying to build but in Tradingview we can do same without indicator like we first select Nifty 23500 call option expiring on 21st november and then select plus symbol and add another symbol nifty 23500 put option expiring on 21st november and then enter so it will plot chart by adding both values. I am doing same in my indicator but high low values are differnet for my indicator comparred to that plotted on tradingview default chart. this is the issue i am tyring to resolve

Can you type here exactly what you enter into the ticker text field? What are the ticker ids for Nifty 23500 call and Nifty 23500 put options?

this is how it exacctly looks for tradingview default chart and for me i enter same symbol as input NIFTY241121P23500+ NSE:NIFTY241121C23500

Also thank you for looking into my issue much appreciated sir.

symbol input:- NIFTY241121P23500
symbol 2 input : -NIFTY241121C23500

hello sir @vitruvius pls update when you can, waiting on you to get some help.

Sorry, I think these symbols are expired now. What would be the new ticker ids for both call and put options?

sorry for late reply been out. My mistake for symbols but now these symbols will expire at 26th december which will allow ample time for debug symbol1:- NIFTY241226P24500 and symbol2:- NIFTY241226C24500 .

pls update when you can sir @vitruvius
